How to find out who recorded an audio file with .m4a extension?
I want to find out person who recorded an audio file with .m4a extension which is sent to me over WhatsApp, also, recording location, recording device.
Is there any tool, program etc. for this?

People can enter anything in metadata. Whatever is written there, it may not be the person who recorded it, nor the person who speaks, nor the location it was recorded, nor the location it was processed.

For which OS do you need such a program? On Windows, you can simply select the file in Explorer, press Alt+Enter and look at the "Details" tab

From what I've seen, WhatsApp strips away all metadata for privacy reasons. If @ThomasWeller suggestion shows nothing, then there probably isn't anything to see.

Ask already mentioned here: https://superuser.com/q/1867419/409497 usually you can't

There seem to be two separate questions asked:

How can I find out who sent me a  over WhatsApp?
How can I inspect embedded metadata in a .m4a file?

